# MySQL json function - querying by DATE

Tags: mysql, json

I would like to query data from MySQL database from JSON type column.

I got a query which works and return data from JSON field:

```
SELECT 
    readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.readTimestamp"
 FROM 
    `readouts_store` 
 WHERE 
    `readout_id`=75898
```

it returns:

```
"2018-02-04 20:11:53"
```

But to limit the selected data by date I need it to something like this:

```
SELECT 
    readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.value" 
 FROM 
    `readouts_store` 
 WHERE 
    `application_id`=1 
 AND
    readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.readTimestamp", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' BETWEEN '2018-02-03' AND '2018-02-05'
```

It doesn't work so I think it is expected that I convert `readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.readTimestamp"` into DATE type like this:

```
SELECT 
    readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.value" 
 FROM 
    `readouts_store` 
 WHERE 
    `application_id`=1 
 AND
    STR_TO_DATE(readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.readTimestamp", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2018-02-03' AND '2018-02-05'
```

unfortunately it doesn't work because STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL:

```
SELECT 
    STR_TO_DATE(readouts->"$.temperature_sensor_1.readTimestamp", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
FROM
    readouts_store
WHERE 
   `readout_id`=75898
```

Instead of STR_TO_DATE() I also tried DATE() and CONVERT("", DATE) but the result is the same.

Is such functionality not supported in MySQL? I cannot find any reference in documentation covering this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `->` the return value is itself a JSON value, so it appears to have double-quotes.

Use `->>` to return a "raw" scalar value with the quotes removed.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html for more information on the difference.